# GONE on first time start up, and VISIBLE after click button, and save the current state for resume

Tags: android

I have a problem here.

Activity A--->B--->C
A is welcome page, B is user account adding page, C is user details input page

I have set 10 rows in my activity B. I want to make it initially in GONE mode when 1st time start up this app, and after I clicked "add", the row will be shown on every single click. If i click next button in my row, I will be directed activity C. Or if I press back in activity B, I will be directed to A.

Now, my prob is, I want to make it initially in GONE mode when 1st time start up this app, and after I clicked "add", the row will be shown on every single click. And also, if i go to C and back to B, or back to A and come back to B, i want the rows that I have shown VISIBLE or GONE remain the previous state. How can I achieve that?

```
public class AccountSetup extends Activity {

    TableRow tableRow1, tableRow2, tableRow3, tableRow4, tableRow5, tableRow6, tableRow7, tableRow8, tableRow9, tableRow10;
    View border1, border2, border3, border4, border5, border6, border7, border8, border9, border10;
    Button iconNext1, iconNext2, iconNext3, iconNext4, iconNext5, iconNext6, iconNext7, iconNext8, iconNext9, iconNext10;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.account_main);
        this.initViews();
        //Set onClick on Button Done
/*      Button btnDone  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDone);       
        btnDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(tableRow1.isSelected()) 
            return;
        }});*/

        //Set onClick on Button Add
        Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);        
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (tableRow1.getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
                    tableRow1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    border1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else if (tableRow2.getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
                        tableRow2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        border2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else if (tableRow3.getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
                        tableRow3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        border3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else if (tableRow4.getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
                        tableRow4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        border4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else if (tableRow5.getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
                        tableRow5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        border5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else if (tableRow6.getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
                        tableRow6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        border6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else if (tableRow7.getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
                        tableRow7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        border7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else if (tableRow8.getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
                        tableRow8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        border8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else if (tableRow9.getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
                        tableRow9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        border9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else if (tableRow10.getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
                        tableRow10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        border10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else {
                        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Message");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("You have reached the maximum number of users");
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tick);
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        });
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }   
        }});
    }

    private void initViews(){ 
        //Account 1  
        tableRow1  = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
        border1    = (View)findViewById(R.id.border1);
        iconNext1  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iconNext1);
        tableRow1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("User Account Deletion");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this user account?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    tableRow1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    border1.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();}});
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
            }});
        tableRow1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Intent1 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, BluGuardProto2Activity.class);
                Intent1.putExtra("activity", "activity1");
                startActivity(Intent1);
                finish();
                }
        });          
        iconNext1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent1 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity1.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent1, 100);
            finish();}});

        //Account 2
        tableRow2  = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);  
        border2    = (View)findViewById(R.id.border2);
        iconNext2  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iconNext2);
        tableRow2.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("User Account Deletion");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this user account?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                tableRow2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                border2.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();}});
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;}});
        tableRow2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    /*tableRow1.setEnabled(true);
                    tableRow1.setSelected(true);
                    tableRow1.requestFocusFromTouch();*/
                    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, BluGuardProto2Activity.class);
                    launchIntent.putExtra("originActivity", this.getClass().getName());
                    startActivityForResult(launchIntent, 250);
                   //Intent Intent2 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, BluGuardProto2Activity.class);
                   //Intent2.putExtra("activity", "activity2");
                   //startActivityForResult(Intent2, 250);
                    }
            });
        iconNext2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent2 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity2.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent2, 200);
            finish();}});

        //Account 3
        tableRow3  = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow3);  
        border3    = (View)findViewById(R.id.border3);
        iconNext3  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iconNext3); 
        tableRow3.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("User Account Deletion");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this user account?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                tableRow3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                border3.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();}});
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;}});   
        iconNext3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent3 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity3.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent3, 300);
            finish();}});

        //Account 4
        tableRow4  = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow4);  
        border4    = (View)findViewById(R.id.border4);
        iconNext4  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iconNext4); 
        tableRow4.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("User Account Deletion");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this user account?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                tableRow4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                border4.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();}});
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;}});              
        iconNext4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent4 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity4.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent4, 400);
            finish();}});

        //Account 5
        tableRow5  = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow5);  
        border5    = (View)findViewById(R.id.border5);
        iconNext5  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iconNext5); 
        tableRow5.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("User Account Deletion");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this user account?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                tableRow5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                border5.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();}});
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;}});
        iconNext5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent5 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity5.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent5, 500);
            finish();}});

        //Account 6
        tableRow6  = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow6);  
        border6    = (View)findViewById(R.id.border6); 
        iconNext6  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iconNext6); 
        tableRow6.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("User Account Deletion");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this user account?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                tableRow6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                border6.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();}});
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;}});    
        iconNext6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent6 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity6.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent6, 600);
            finish();}});

        //Account 7
        tableRow7  = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow7);  
        border7    = (View)findViewById(R.id.border7); 
        iconNext7  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iconNext7);
        tableRow7.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("User Account Deletion");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this user account?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                tableRow7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                border7.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();}});
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;}});    
        iconNext7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent7 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity7.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent7, 700);
            finish();}});

        //Account 8
        tableRow8  = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow8);  
        border8    = (View)findViewById(R.id.border8);  
        iconNext8  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iconNext8);
        tableRow8.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("User Account Deletion");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this user account?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                tableRow8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                border8.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();}});
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;}});    
        iconNext8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent8 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity8.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent8, 800);
            finish();}});

        //Account 9
        tableRow9  = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow9);  
        border9    = (View)findViewById(R.id.border9);  
        iconNext9  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iconNext9);
        tableRow9.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("User Account Deletion");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this user account?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                tableRow9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                border9.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();}});
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;}});     
        iconNext9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent9 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity9.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent9, 900);
            finish();}});

        //Account 10
        tableRow10  = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow10);  
        border10    = (View)findViewById(R.id.border10);
        iconNext10  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iconNext10);
        tableRow10.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountSetup.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("User Account Deletion");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this user account?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                tableRow10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                border10.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();}});
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;}});      
        iconNext10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent10 = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity10.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent10, 1000);
            finish();}});
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(i);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        // When user leaves this tab, saves the values
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       if (requestCode == 100) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {    
               data.getStringExtra("accountName1");
               TextView user1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user1);  
               user1.setText(sp.getString("accountName1", ""));}} 
       else if (requestCode == 200) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
               data.getStringExtra("accountName2");   
               TextView user2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user2);  
               user2.setText(sp.getString("accountName2", ""));}}
       else if (requestCode == 300) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
               data.getStringExtra("accountName3");   
               TextView user3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user3);  
               user3.setText(sp.getString("accountName3", ""));}}
       else if (requestCode == 400) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
               data.getStringExtra("accountName4");   
               TextView user4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user4);  
               user4.setText(sp.getString("accountName4", ""));}}
       else if (requestCode == 500) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
               data.getStringExtra("accountName5");   
               TextView user5  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user5);  
               user5.setText(sp.getString("accountName5", ""));}}
       else if (requestCode == 600) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
               data.getStringExtra("accountName6");   
               TextView user6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user6);  
               user6.setText(sp.getString("accountName6", ""));}}
       else if (requestCode == 700) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
               data.getStringExtra("accountName7");   
               TextView user7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user7);  
               user7.setText(sp.getString("accountName7", ""));}}
       else if (requestCode == 800) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
               data.getStringExtra("accountName8");   
               TextView user8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user8);  
               user8.setText(sp.getString("accountName8", ""));}}
       else if (requestCode == 900) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
               data.getStringExtra("accountName9");   
               TextView user9 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user9);  
               user9.setText(sp.getString("accountName9", ""));}}
       else if (requestCode == 1000) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
               data.getStringExtra("accountName10");   
               TextView user10 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user10);  
               user10.setText(sp.getString("accountName10", ""));}}
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        onSaveSettings();
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        TextView user1  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user1);
        user1.setText(sp.getString("accountName1", ""));
        TextView user2  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user2);
        user2.setText(sp.getString("accountName2", ""));
        TextView user3  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user3);
        user3.setText(sp.getString("accountName3", ""));
        TextView user4  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user4);
        user4.setText(sp.getString("accountName4", ""));
        TextView user5  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user5);
        user5.setText(sp.getString("accountName5", ""));
        TextView user6  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user6);
        user6.setText(sp.getString("accountName6", ""));
        TextView user7  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user7);
        user7.setText(sp.getString("accountName7", ""));
        TextView user8  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user8);
        user8.setText(sp.getString("accountName8", ""));
        TextView user9  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user9);
        user9.setText(sp.getString("accountName9", ""));
        TextView user10 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user10);
        user10.setText(sp.getString("accountName10", ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tprefernce values to save the state of each row. so when you exit the activity save values of rows (active or not), and when you start the activity load values to active or not rows.

Here's an example:

```
public static void updateBooleanValue(boolean value, int id, Context context)
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Editor edit = preferences.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(context.getResources().getString(id), value);
    edit.commit();
}

public static boolean getBoolPreference(int id, Context context)
{
    // Initialize preferences
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getBoolean(context.getResources().getString(id), false);

}
```

- the function updateBooleanValue set the state of the current row (true or false)
- the function getBoolPreference get the state of the current row (true or false)
- the id is for example R.String.id that you set in the string.xml

that's all.

Good Luck.

Comment: Do you mind to show me by modifying my code and show me here?I am confused on your concept:-(

Comment: the main goal of the above code is to save data even if application is closed. So my idea is to save for each arrow a boolean data when you close the activity. on re-opening the activity you should read saved booleans to put row active or not. is the idea clear for you?

Comment: do u mind write me a sample of code using my example?I try to write based on this concept but I can't get it:-(

Comment: :-(
so sad that I am still noob in getting that~:-(

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `ListView` and add and delete rows dynamically, and you want to use arrays instead of variables 1 to 10. [This example](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/), for instance, demonstrates how to start a new activity from clicking on an item in a `ListView`:

```
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView); // You need to add this!

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          Intent intent = new Intent(AccountSetup.this, AccountSettingActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("rowNumber", position);
          startActivityForResult(intent, position * 100);
      }
    });
```

It's difficult for me to give you more detailed help without completely rewriting your code, however.

Comment: I know what you meant. I have been using this method before this. But unfortunately, I took up few weeks and still unable to make it until this current state. I gave up and use this method instead. I know it is stupid to use this method, as it is very lengthy code and make my app bigger, but I have no other choice but to continue it this way.